# Jquery Slider using div and with pagination

Tags: jquery, html, css, pagination

I'm trying to create a image slider where in images are place inside a DIV.
So basically, I have 3 divs, they can be control using a href html, the first one, its function will move to the first div, second move to center div, and last move to the 3rd div the last one. I think this is called pagination? Correct me if I'm wrong. I did not place an image on the div to simplify the codes.

```
    <a href="" id="show1">Move to first div</a>
    <a href="" id="show2">Move to center</a>
    <a href="" id="show3">Move to 3rd div</a>

    <div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><div id="div1" class="divstyle">this is first</div></li>
                <li><div id="div2" class="divstyle">this is second</div></li>
                <li><div id="div3" class="divstyle">this is third</div></li>
            </ul>

    </div>
   </div>
```

This is how I tested it in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#show1').click(function() {
  $('ul li div').animate({
   left: '-=450'
  }, 3000, function() {
  // Animation complete.
  });

});     

});
```

I used the selector (ul li div) and used animate(), I tested a simple moving to the left, but it is not working. Any idea on this one?

Basically this is what I'm trying to achieve.

 http://theme.crumina.net/onetouch2/

This is the css ,.

```
<style>
    .divstyle 
    {

        text-align: center;
        width:450px;
        height:300px;
        border:1px solid #000;  


        margin: auto;
    }

    #inner-wrapper ul li
    {
        list-style:none; 
        position:relative;
        float:left;


    }
    #inner-wrapper li

    {
        display: inline;
    }


    #main-wrapper
    {
        position: relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        width:100%;
        border:1px solid #000;
        height: 350px;
        float:left;
    }

    #inner-wrapper
    {

        display: table;   /* Allow the centering to work */
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        height: 300px;
        width:500px;
        border:1px solid #000;

        overflow: hidden;

    }



</style>
```

Comment: Please post any CSS you have as well. You should at least be using `position: relative` on the <ul> and  `position: absolute` on the <li> elements

Comment: @user3627265 I have refactored your html, and js. See my answer and demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602373/jquery-slider-using-div-and-with-pagination/23602759#23602759)

Comment: I did see your answer, and it looks great, 
I'm just wondering what is the problem, my css or something else? hmm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/RG47P/)**

First you need to refactor your html like;

```
<a href="#" data-id="-450" class="paginate">Move to first div</a>
    <a href="#" data-id="0" class="paginate">Move to center</a>
    <a href="#" data-id="+450" class="paginate">Move to 3rd div</a>

    <div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><div id="div1" class="divstyle">this is first</div></li>
                <li><div id="div2" class="divstyle">this is second</div></li>
                <li><div id="div3" class="divstyle">this is third</div></li>
            </ul>

    </div>
   </div>
```

As you can see I have put position value in `data-id`, and added `#` to href links. And your js will be;

```
$('.paginate').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var amount = $(this).data("id");
  $("#main-wrapper").animate({
   left: amount
  }, 1000, function() {
  });

});
```

Comment: Hmm.. Nice work. But What I'm trying to achieve is the ul li to animate, not the whole div inner wrapper. Its like moving from list to list. just like the link I have posted. http://theme.crumina.net/onetouch2/

Comment: But you are wrong. Sliders generaly made of the logic that I gave you in my demo. You have list and wrapping div outside of that list. You move wrapper div left or right. When you move wrapper div, the list inside also moves.  If you animate div inside of wrapper, when you move a `li` element to left, you need to move all other li s to left. Think my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You should uniquely identify the div tio apply animation. also you have to make the position absolute. Try the below code

```
$('#show1').click(function() {    
  $( "#div1" ).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
});     

CSS:
 .divstyle {    position: absolute;    background-color: #abc;    left: 50px;  }
```

Check it here :http://jsfiddle.net/2N76g/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#show1').click(function() {
  $('div').animate({
   left: '-=450'
  }, 3000, function() {
  // Animation complete.
  });

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/naB6C/)